# How to deal with console logging?

Tags: c#, logging, microsoft.extensions.logging

My apps logs structured (json) logs to STDOUT. When someone does something like `Console.Write("Foo")` it will mess up json parser and log pipeline will yell at me.

How to prevent anything but my logger output end up in STDOUT? Keep in mind that even if I remove all `Console.Write` occurances in my code, something may reside in one of multiple libraries I'm including in my product - debuging this is a nightmare.

I must log to the console, platform (kubernetes) requires it.

Comment: Well, then can't you log to another target / sink (whatever you call it)? Like a File or DB or MessageQueue?

Comment: If you *must* log to the console (or any other shared output medium you don't control) then one option could be to prepend all of your known log entries with a known string value, and whatever downstream parsing logic you use can ignore any lines which don't start with that value.

Comment: What if 3rd Party uses Console.Write and you can't change it? You want to drop that? Whatever you do you need to fix that in the pipeline. And personally i would rather wrap unstructured stuff into a structure there instead of dropping it.

Comment: It seems quite odd to have libraries using standard output.  Unless it's specifically some sort of library designed around supporting a shell-based UI, I wouldn't expect any library to touch standard output.  At most I'd perhaps expect it to have some diagnostic info to it but only if it could easily be enabled/disabled.

Comment: @Servy The don't do it directly. Question is tagged with Extensions.Logging and he has presumably a setup for that to output to the standard output so anyone using ILogger will go to the Console. Standard in a Kubernetes setup and not uncommon for packages to really on ILogger.  And as he added Kubernetes by now he has presumably not only 3rd party libraries in his services but complete 3rd party containers running in his cluster that do whatever they like to on the console.

Comment: @Servy I agree with you, but people tend to do console debugging, and if you encounter this it's pretty challenging and time consuming to sort it out (you have to submit changes and wait for release).

Comment: @Ralf I'd say that library should integrate into some kind of logging mechanism instead of just trowing stuff at console. 3rd party library using Console.Write is exactly my problem, on the other hand logging to console is my requirement from devops.

Comment: Sure, casual developers do use the console to debug, but to see it out of a library is a pretty stuffed look.  Honestly if I saw that behavior out of a library it's such a red flag that I'm not sure I'd trust it in any production codebase.  Rather than trying to get them to remove it I'd just look to move on to a different library or other means of doing whatever it was doing.  It suggests their library is very unfinished and that the developer(s) aren't testing it very much at all that random debugging code was left in.

Comment: I agree in theory, but in practice I came across some interesting implementations, mostly debug logging in logging libraries (i.e. kind of internal logger), and similar use cases, or some random console logs left by someone in some internal shared libraries in my company (not really sure why). However I see your point, I think your comment could be an answer, and then people could vote for it. Maybe just nailing down all these console logs is the way :)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO dealing with it in your code is prohibitively expensive. Nobody sane would print directly to `Console` in library, so unless you are dealing with extreme case the author of the closed-source library died, I would simply reach out to the author and point a bug in his/her code rather than change my code around it. Fixing the issue would benefit not only you, but everybody using the library including its author.